# How to make the View scrollable - View contain a stack with labels and image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

[second image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWlZr.png)I have created a `UIViewController` with 4 `UILabels` and an `UIImageView`, embedded in a `UIStackView`. When I add a text into the second label, the length of the label increases and goes beyond the safe-areas. I tried putting a `UIScrollView` but it doesn't work.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci4rm.png) is a screenshot of my Storyboard
[updated image View added]

Comment: put your stack view inside scroll view, not near

Comment: @PhilipDukhov how to do it

Comment: Welcome to the community. You can do this by dragging your `StackView` inside your `ScrollView`

Comment: @VisalRajapakse i have done like that. refer my screenshot

Comment: Check my answer, your Stackview is **ABOVE** your Scrollview, not **INSIDE** it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, according to your screenshot, your view hierarchy is like follows:

```
|-Scroll View
|---Content Layout Guide 
|---Frame Layout Guide.       
|-Stack View
|---Some content
.
.
.
|
```

You can drag your `Stack View` inside the `Scroll View` so that the hierarchy looks like the following

```
|-Scroll View
|---Stack View <---------------- Drag your stackview inside scroll view
|------Some content
|---Content Layout Guide 
|---Frame Layout Guide.       
.
.
.
|
```

Comment: I tried to drag it but not working

Comment: Not working as in?

Comment: When I undo checkmark in scroll view that Content Layout gone. and i have put stack View inside Scroll View the Stack Alignment have gone wrong

Comment: Can you update your answer so I can see the hierarchy

Comment: I have added  <https://github.com/jestinsaji/ios.git>

Comment: @JESTINSAJI Is the problem solved or not?

Comment: @matt problem is not solved

Comment: @JESTINSAJI Then why did you accept this answer? That closes out the question-answer cycle; it says "done, nothing to see here".

Comment: @matt i dint know about that